# Excel VBA Copy and Paste different workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy one worksheet's data (Workbook: Segmented General Ledger Trial Balance.XLS - sheet inside this workbook has the same name) to another workbook with 20 sheets in it, one of them with the same name Pasting the data over the existing data.

Code look like:

```
Sub CopyWorkbook()

    Dim aw As Workbook
    Dim y As Workbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    Set aw = Application.ActiveWorkbook
    Set y = Application.Workbooks.Open("S:\Proefbalanse\PastelTB\Segmented General Ledger Trial Balance.XLS")

    For i = 20 To aw.Sheets.Count
            Set sh = Segmented General Ledger Trial ***its complaining about this sheet name***

        On Error Resume Next
        Set sh = y.Worksheets(aw.Worksheets(i).Name)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If TypeName(sh) <> "Segmented General Ledger Trial" Then
            sh.Range("A:F").Copy aw.Worksheets(i).Range("A1")
        End If
    Next i
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   y.Close
End Sub
```

When I change the sheet names in both worksbook it runs through without pasting the data in the correct sheet?

Please help.

Johan

Comment: It is not complaining about that sheet name. It is complaining about the words you've placed in the middle of your sub not being proper syntax. Judging from the code two lines down you should know how to properly reference a worksheet. Furthermore, I believe [TypeName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/typename-function) does not do what you think it does.  Again, judging from the code two lines further up, you should know what property to use.

Comment: Hi DaFois 
Thank you for replying the words I put in *** is just to say what it is complaining about, it's not part of the code. When I put the sheet name in, it flags it red. I'm still a little confuse. I've tried underscore but it didn't help.